# Responsive background image with navbar menu buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, background-image, navbar

In Bootstrap 3 I have a navbar that contains background image and some menu items under the image:

[image]

Here is css for background image:

```
.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-top: 25px;
    background: url(../Content/images/1.png),    url(../Content/images/2.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: -25px 0px, 528px 54px;
```

Those are two images and I have to specify position in pixels in order to glue them together.

I am also using navbar-right to place menu items right under the image:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.navbar-left {
    float: left !important;
}

.navbar-right {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 150px;
}

    .navbar-right ~ .navbar-right {
        margin-right: 50px;
    }
}
```

It all works fine until I make screen size really small, then my menu items are pushed to the left:

[image]

I am wondering how to keep those menu items relative to the background image e.g. responsive.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the design you are aiming for, you might want to think of another way to put it on a mobile device.

If that is how you want it, perhaps standard test instead of the blocks. I usually create smaller images for my mobile devices and let CSS control them if need be.

I always add

```
img{width:100%}
```

My images are a percent and not a pixel. So if/when a different device looks at it, they adjust. However, I create different size images usually. My logo is bigger on a desktop vs a mobile device vs a tablet. I know I did not answer your immediate question, but hopefully I made you think a little bit more about the option(s).